# Screen and audio replication software

Tags: windows, osx, video, audio

I'm looking for a way to replicate screen and audio from a Mac computer to a "window" on a windows machine.

Ideally, it would be best for the video replication part to work as a secondary monitor (virtual) in the mac, so powerpoint can play there and be controlled from monitor 1, like a true secondary monitor.

Is there any software that does this or a USB hardware device that I can use for this purpose?

I don't need to display to a projector, but from a Mac laptop to a Windows machine, in some sort of movable window on the Windows machine or a virtual capture device would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A program called AirParrot 2 mixed with the receiver program Reflector 3 does the job.

AirParrot 2 is the sending program, it gives the Mac or PC sending a Virtual Screen and allows you to size the screen to the dimensions you want.

Then on the receiving PC or Mac you install Reflector 3 from the same company, this will then broadcast itself over the network (both devices need to be on the same network). On the sending side in AirParrot 2 you select the receiver device and it instantly sends both audio and video to Reflector 3.

Reflector 3 shows the sending sides screen as a new window, that you can move, and also make full screen for instance if you want to move the window to your secondary monitor to project full screen to a projector.

[AirParrot 2](https://www.airsquirrels.com/airparrot/)

[Reflector 3](https://www.airsquirrels.com/reflector)

Both programs work on Mac and Windows, so you can effectively use a laptop as a presenter over the network.